# What volumes of the graphic novel does the XIII adventure game cover?

Tags: xiii

Anuman Interactive released a graphical adventure game based on the Belgian graphic novel *XIII* in 2011, titled *XIII: Lost Identity*. So far, I have read only up to volume 5 of 19 in the graphic novel series, and I want to avoid having parts of the story spoiled to me by the game.

How many of the 19 volumes does the adventure game deal with?

Note that this is not about the 2003 FPS also titled *XIII* and based on the same graphic novel series (covering volumes 1-5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A review of the game mentions this:

> [T]he plot is basically a retread of what’s been included in the previous game[.]

The previous game covered [the first 5 volumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XIII_%28video_game%29), so if you've finished volume 5, you should be fine.

Note that the review also states that this is more of a "hidden object finding" game than a traditional adventure game.  It might be worth reading the review before you pony up the cash to make sure you're interested in what you're buying.

Comment: It is "safe" then, thanks! I will also re-evaluate whether the amount of actual narrative it contains is worth the asking price.